# HTML CSS Container with overflow scroll but have one element overflow visible

Tags: html, css

I have a table, containing rows, where each row has an expandable menu with `position: absolute` to the right hand side of the row.  I'm having issues trying to get the menu to display beyond the boundary of the table, given the table has `overflow: scroll`.  Is it possible to have the menu be visible?  I've tried various variations of nested `absolute` and `relative` wrappers around the menu, and also z-index, but no luck.

I need the result to look like -

[image]

fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/oet3mrjn/2/

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.row {
  height:50px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    row
    <div class="menu">
      menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont' understand your question. You need to row to be inside red rectangle under menu?

Comment: I need the menu to be visible beyond the table boundary, i've updated the question with a screenshot of what im trying to achieve.  Im not sure it possible, but its the markup ive been left to work with :(

Answer (score 0):

I *think* i see your problem here.

It seems like your overflow is the cause of the issue.

```
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
```

}

Have a look at this fiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/0cz18fhL/

Comment: Please do not post the solution in a fiddle.  Post it in a _working Snippet_ in your answer.

Comment: thanks though that makes the rows also overflow.  Its like I need a mixture of both `overflow: scroll` for the sake of the rows, but need `overflow: visible` for the sake of the menu...

Comment: Check answer above @andymccullough

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;

  
}

.row {
  height: 50px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: white;
  /* right: 20px; */
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    row
    <div class="menu">
      menu
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    row
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, looks like menu in the table as whole though, the menu should be per row, so technically 3 collapsable menus should exist in this example

Comment: That is not what your image looks like, you should update your question to reflect this

Comment: so you want the menu collapsible on click or just a dropdown?

Comment: the first line of the question says - "I have a table, containing rows, where each row has an expandable menu with position: absolute to the right hand side".  The collapsing is not the issue, its the fact the menu can't overflow the table is the problem.  The menu in the example is demonstrating it from its expanded state. Normally it would be hidden behind 3 dots / burger menu